# Location Button doesn't work GoogleMaps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to get my current location with the location button on Google Maps but I have some problems. With the new runtime permissions (API level 23), I don't know if i am doing well or not.
With that code below, when I use a virtual device API 23, the location button doesn't appear and with a virtual device API 22, it appears but don't do anything. So what can be the problem ?

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback{
```

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        // Show rationale and request permission.
    }

}
```

}

In the Manifest file :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

In api level 23, you need check permissions programmatically. You are checking the location permission and if it's granted, setting the location enabled. You can ask for permission if it is not granted.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Then you can handle the result by overriding this method.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //do something
            } else {
                finish();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can give permission from the emulator's settings for your application.

Let me know after trying. Good luck.

EDIT:
You need to implement a clicklistener to mylocation button.

```
final GoogleMap mMap = map; 
map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
            LatLng loc = new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(),mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said. I allow for my position. So now, the location button appears. But, on click, it doesn't do anything.. I want that, on click, the camera move on my position. How is it possible with api level 23 ?
I used to do that before these runtime permissions with just this line "    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);" but i don't know how it works with this one..

Comment: Please be sure the button can be clickable. Because in my layout it was under a toolbar and it could not be clicked. When i removed the toolbar it worked.

Comment: @Irving-Zamora comments: On the OnMyLocationButtonClickListener you have to return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs i.e. (the camera animates to the user's current position).